# Why am I getting this error "Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : argument "cla" is missing, with no default"

Tags: r, function, apply

I am trying to apply a function to a series of inputs and I am having this error. I don't understand why since I believe I am passing the values of "cla" in the dataframe I am providing. Sorry if this is a too basic question, but I cannot figure it out. Below is a reproducible example.

The output I need is the responseRate for each row of the "inputs" dataframe.

Thanks in advance.

```
inputs <- data.frame(P=c(0, 50, 80, 100),
                     pd=c(38, 50, 50, 86),
                     cla=c(15, 40, 30, 81))

eq1 <- function(a,b,c,x){
        (a*exp(-((((exp(b)*x))/1000))+c+b))/1000
}

resp.function <- function(pd, cla, eq1, P){
        a <- 70 + pd*80 + cla*80
        b <- 1
        c <- 70 + pd*10
        responseRate <- eq1(a,b,c,P)
        return(responseRate)
}


apply(inputs, 1, resp.function)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass `eq1` in `resp.function`.

```
resp.function <- function(pd, cla, P){
   a <- 70 + pd*80 + cla*80
   b <- 1
   c <- 70 + pd*10
   responseRate <- eq1(a,b,c,P)
   return(responseRate)
}
```

Moreover, your function is vectorized so you can do :

```
resp.function(inputs$P, inputs$pd, inputs$cla)
```

---

If the function is not vectorized, you could use `mapply` to apply it for every value in the row.

```
mapply(resp.function, inputs$P, inputs$pd, inputs$cla)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked! Just curious how you can tell the function is vectorized or it is not? What does that mean?

Comment: We have a vectorized function when you pass a vector as input to the function and the function is applied to all the inputs simultaneously without any need of `for` loop or `apply` family of functions. For example, `sqrt(1:10)` gives square root for all the input 1 to 10, we don't have to pass each value individually to `sqrt` function.

Comment: can I ask you one more question? I am trying to get all the outputs from the function, so used `newlist <- list(a, b, c, responseRate)' and `return(newlist)'.  When having only one return I used this to accommodate the result in a table: ` input$responseRate <-resp.function(inputs$P, inputs$pd, inputs$cla)`. But now I am having problem adding the outputs a, b, c... Any hint? Thanks so much!

Comment: I came up with this solution. But I think is too wordy... `results <- as.data.frame(t(mapply(resp.function, inputs$P, inputs$pd, inputs$cla))) %>% rename(a=V1, b=V2, c=V3, responseRate=V4)` and `inputs2 <- cbind(inputs, results)`

Comment: I am not sure if I exactly understand but you could give name to your input to `mapply`/`Map` `mapply(resp.function, a = inputs$P, b = inputs$pd, c = inputs$cla)`

Comment: No, I meant to have the objects a, b, and c, that are within the function, as an output of the function. Sorry if I am not being clear.